# How can I create an array of references to arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I am attempting to write an array that contains references to three other arrays in Perl, but I am receiving compilation errors whenever I do. Can I not reference arrays in this way, or am I attempted to reference the array I have created wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @person1 = [ "Mike S", 32, 40000];
my @person2 = [ "Jim B", 54, 50000];
my @person3 = [ "Heather Q", 29, 60000];

my @ref1 = \@person1;
my @ref2 = \@person2;
my @ref3 = \@person3;

my @bigArray = [ @ref1, @ref2, @ref3];

for (my $i = 0; $i < $#bigArray; $i++) {
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $#bigArray[$i]; $j++) {
                print $bigArray[$i][$j];
        }
}
```

Comment: `@array = [ ... ]` should generate a warning (I mean it doesn't, but it should).

Comment: @mob: no, it shouldn't, since that is perfectly valid and useful.

Comment: Valid and useful, yes, but often not what the user means (like the OP). If that's what you want to say, `@array = ( [ ... ] )` makes it more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

First things first. `[]` creates an array ref, not a list and array refs are scalars.

So:

```
my @person1 = [ "Mike S", 32, 40000];
```

Creates an array containing an array ref.

And then:

```
my @ref1 = \@person1;
```

… creates an array containing a reference to that array.

So forget all that and go direct to array refs in scalars.

```
my $ref1 = [ "Mike S", 32, 40000];
my $ref2 = [ "Jim B", 54, 50000];
my $ref3 = [ "Heather Q", 29, 60000];
```

Next up, you do the same thing here:

```
my @bigArray = [ @ref1, @ref2, @ref3];
```

You probably actually want an array, so put a list on the right hand side instead of an array ref.

```
my @bigArray = ( $ref1, $ref2, $ref3 );
```

Idiomatic Perl avoids using index variables when you don't need them.

So just loop over the items in the array:

```
for my $ref (@bigArray) {
```

Then do the same thing for each array reference inside. The trick here is that you have to deference the arrayref first, with `@`.

```
for my $item (@$ref) {
```

Thus giving you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ref1 = [ "Mike S", 32, 40000];
my $ref2 = [ "Jim B", 54, 50000];
my $ref3 = [ "Heather Q", 29, 60000];

my @bigArray = ( $ref1, $ref2, $ref3 );

for my $ref (@bigArray) {
    for my $item (@$ref) {
        print $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `[ ... ]` to assing to array variables. Square brackets are used for array references.

Keep array references in scalar variables, not in arrays.

When iterating over the array, the end condition is `<= $#`, otherwise you miss the last element.

```
my @person1 = ( "Mike S", 32, 40000 );
my @person2 = ( "Jim B", 54, 50000 );
my @person3 = ( "Heather Q", 29, 60000 );

my $ref1 = \@person1;
my $ref2 = \@person2;
my $ref3 = \@person3;

my @bigArray = ( $ref1, $ref2, $ref3 );

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#bigArray; $i++) {
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#{$bigArray[$i]}; $j++) {
                print $bigArray[$i][$j];
        }
}
```

To avoid off-by-one errors, you can iterate over the indices using the range operator:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#bigArray) {
    for my $j (0 .. $#{ $bigArray[$i] }) {
        print $bigArray[$i][$j];
    }
}
```